# Non-Live Android App does not show AdMob Ads or Videos unless using a registered Test Device

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android app, which:

- is not currently deployed to the App Store
- has AdMob Banner and Video Ads

I have setup some Banner and Reward Video Ads in the AdMob Console

- these Ads are **correctly** displayed on my registered Test Device

However

- these Ads are **not** displayed on non-test devices
- when I also register these devices as test devices, the ads start to work as expected

Questions

1. Why do the Banner Ads not show on the non-test devices..? Is it because the App is not Live yet..?
2. Do I need to deploy the App to the PlayStore to get my Banner / Video Ads to work on non-test devices..?

Thank You

Comment: To see ads live you have to upload the app on `play-store` 
and try to use  sample id provided by Google 
`Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713`

Comment: @Sniffer. Thanks for your reply. I have used the Sample Test IDs during initial development and they work fine.

My own Ad Unit IDs also work, but only on test Devices.

Comment: @Sniffer Can you please refer to the source of the sample app ID? I didn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: @mdehghani check [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample ads (registered devices or sample IDs) are shown without limits, after all they are test ads for testing. (So, real ads in a test device, that's fine. Sample ads in a non-test device, that's fine. Real ads in a non-test device, that's not fine, because it's like you're trying to monetize the app, without being linked to a Store or without having been
reviewed by AdMob)

True, monetizable ads, on the other hand, come at the end of a process.
First you have to upload the application to a supported Store, then you have to link the Store App to AdMob, then AdMob performs the review of the app to verify that it complies with their policies, and then the real ads appears.